# nvl sql - checking value not equal to 0 for null values

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a better way to write `NVL(qty,0) <> 0` in oracle instead of first converting it from null ( if it is null ) to 0 and then checking if it is not 0. It works, but, I am wondering if there is any other way.

Comment: doesn't `qty <> 0` works the same in this case?. It won't return `NULL` values

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks, I was aggressively checking for non-nulls.

Comment: @would_like_to_be_anon In some cases you do need to check for `null`s. _Any_ condition that compares something to null will _always_ return false. That is, both `qty <> 0` and `qty = 0` return false when `qty` is `null`. That happens to be OK in your example, but will not be in others.